# vb.net code works on IE but not on chrome or Firefox

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have .net code that works on IE8 but wont work on google chrome or firefox. i have put this code for the user to press Enter instead of clicking the mouse everytime.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        If Not IsPostBack Then
           //-- my code --
            Form.DefaultButton = ButContinue.UniqueID
    Catch ex As Threading.ThreadAbortException
    Catch ex As Exception
        ReportError(ex, Session, Request)
    End Try
End Sub
```

How can i make this work on different browsers?

Comment: yes this is asp.net (vb.net code)

Comment: This is server side code.  Browser shouldn't matter because it executes on the server.  Perhaps your error is some where else?

Comment: This server-side code influences what script is render on the client.  ASP.Net renders different script for different browsers, hence the possible difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Form.DefaultButton = ButContinue.ClientID
```

Comment: Yes, this has to be implemented with ClientID to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem could be caused by how ASP.Net renders the client script to handle DefaultButton.  Below are 2 links that sound similar to your problem and both mention issues with button types (button/link/image) and interaction with validation controls (their client-side script at least).  ASP.Net renders different script per browser for these controls/behaviours and on some browsers they conflict.

- http://weblogs.asp.net/efrancobisi/archive/2007/03/15/panel-s-defaultbutton-whims-not-every-ibuttoncontrol-is-the-same.aspx
- http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/453148-asp-net-2-0-multiple-problems-defaultbutton

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to press enter to submit a form instead of clicking a submit button, have you considered using a Panel?

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
    <%-- Form elements go here --%>
</asp:Panel>
```